# How to show an alert before the user closes the browser, without interacting with the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to show an `alert` that asks the user to give some feedback before leaving the page.

I found this code on GeeksforGeeks and it works perfectly fine, the only problem is that it requires the user to type something into the `textarea` before showing the `alert`. If the user types nothing in the textarea and closes the browser there won't be an `alert`.

Does anyone have an idea how I can show this alert, even if the user does not interact with the textarea at all? I already tried to give the textarea a value through jQuery and just hiding it, but this does not work.

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Comment: The code you've shown does not require a user to interact with the `textarea` for the message to be shown. It is shown every time the `beforeunload` event fires. You can see this happening by right clicking in the snippet I edited in to your question and clicking 'reload frame'. As such, it already solves your problem.

Comment: @Rory: [Some browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeUnloadEvent#Browser_compatibility) do require interaction for the dialog to appear, though.

Comment: @DavidHedlund good point, I had neglected that fact. There's no workaround for this if the browser requires user interaction before allowing the notification to be raised from `beforeunload`